# eliminate trailing spaces in url

Tags: python

If a url has trailing spaces in it.how to find them and eliminate the trailing space ..

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cs3ROFNxa5M`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`myString.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html)